# Formating string using Numeral.js

Tags: javascript, numeral.js

How can I format a number respecting the last two number as decimals?

```
1000 -> 10,00

123456 -> 1.234,56
```

I am trying the code below but it won't work keeping the last two places as decimals.

```
fromat(value) {
             return value === null ? "0,00" :  Numeral(value).format('0,0[.]00');
            },
```

Thank you.

Comment: There are numerous examples on [their website](http://numeraljs.com/), along with [information about registering locales](http://numeraljs.com/#locales). Please show what you've tried or what it is you don't understand.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am using format('0,0[.]00'); - And it won't work. They don't have an example in their page about this format.

Comment: Look at the second link. There are options for `delimiters`: `thousands` and `decimal`. Using a little logic, one should come up with appropriate values to set those options to, to produce the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
Numeral(`${value.toString().slice(0, -2)}.${value.toString().slice(-2)}`).format('$ 0,0.00')
```